# How to write in excel no more than 1 million records from python data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python data frame with more than 50 million records. I want to write them into a excel sheet where each sheet should have no more than 1 million records in them.

Comment: You can do it with the tabs but im not sure how you can do it with python :P You may have to edit the DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.iloc` to access certain rows of your data, and then dump them to Excel. Here's an example where 1000 rows are posted per sheet, the same basic idea will apply when you up it to 1000000:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Val': [i for i in range(5000)]})

GROUP_LENGTH = 1000

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')

for i in range(0, len(df), GROUP_LENGTH):
    print(i)
    df.iloc[i:i+GROUP_LENGTH,].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Row {}'.format(i))

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Do we make changes for range(5000) also? or only group_length change is enough?

Comment: @Krishnamurthy the `range(5000)` section is just to give some example data, in your case you'll already have `df` or whatever your dataframe is called.

Comment: for key2 in df['Seller Name'].unique():  
    dw1 = df[df['Seller Name']==key2]
    dw2=pd.DataFrame({'Val':[i for i in range(df)]})
    GROUP_LENGTH=1000000
    for i in range (0, len(dw2), GROUP_LENGTH):
        dw2.iloc[i:i+GROUP_LENGTH,],dw1.to_csv(key2+ ".csv", header=True,index=False)  this si the code i am using and i am getting an error "TypeError: 'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: You're misunderstanding - you don't need `dw2` at all. You do not need the `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` line from my code at all - take all the lines that follow it and replace any time I've used `df` with `dw1`.

Comment: will it give me for unique seller name.i.e. for each seller name i want the output to have the seller name as a part for the excel file name (don't mind even if it is a csv). so if i have 10 sellers i need 10 files alternatively if in a seller 1 i have 15 MN records it should split into 2 files as "seller 1_file 1. csv" and "seller 1_file 2. csv"

Comment: if i run the above code with only one addition index=False in the first instant i am not getting the output for some of the supplier. the code i am using currently is as <pre><code>   for key2 in df['Seller Name'].unique():  
        dw1 = df[df['Seller Name']==key2]
        GROUP_LENGTH=1000000
        writer=pd.ExcelWriter(key2+'.xlsx')
        for i in range (0, len(dw1), GROUP_LENGTH):
            print (i)
            dw1.iloc[i:i+GROUP_LENGTH,].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key2+' Row{}'.format(i),index=False)

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to split your df into 50 df's inside a list and then:

```
for i in range(50):
    list[i].to_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name = f"Sheet{i+1}")
```

Comment: but the problem here is that the database is not constant it might have more or even less so i want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

At first split the data you have and save in various variables...here I have fetched 2.5 million data from database and split them into three(as many you need in your case) variables...

```
pserializer=fetchdataSerializers(all_dataobj,many=True)
res = [item for item in pserializer.data if 1 <= item.get('id') <= 1000000]   
res1 = [item for item in pserializer.data if 1 <= item.get('id') > 1000000 and 
item.get('id') <= 2000000 ]  
res2 = [item for item in pserializer.data if 1 <= item.get('id') > 2000000]
```

Then declare three(as many you need in your case) different dataframes.....

```
df = pd.DataFrame([])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([])
```

Then append them and write them in an excel sheet having three(as many you need in your case) different sub sheets...

```
df = df.append(res)
df1 = df1.append(res1)
df2 = df2.append(res2)

writer = ExcelWriter('fetchdata_sheet15.xlsx')

df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)

df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2',index=False)

df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet3',index=False)

writer.save()
```

That is it.Check if it works for you...Thank You.